# Problem with D3D & COM

Tags: c++, com, visual-c++, direct3d, iunknown

all the D3D interfaces are derived from COM's IUnknown interface, so I though I'd take an easy route for releasing D3D objects and use something like this:

```
__inline BOOL SafeRelease(IUnknown*& pUnknown)
{
    if(pUnknown != NULL && FAILED(pUnknown->Release()))
        return FALSE;

    pUnknown = NULL;
    return TRUE;
}
```

this doesn't work though, as the compiler will generate invalid type conversion error(s), when I try to use it. the only way around it I could think of was this:

```
__inline BOOL SafeRelease(void* pObject)
{
    IUnknown* pUnknown = static_cast<IUnknown*>pObject;
    if(pUnknown != NULL && FAILED(pUnknown->Release()))
        return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}
```

but then I loose some functionality and it also looks(and is) very dodgy. is there a better way to do this? something that works like my first example would be optimal, though I would like to avoid using any macros(if its possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A template function solves your problem:

```
template<class T>
__inline bool SafeRelease(T*& pUnknown)
{
    if (pUnknown == NULL) return false;
    if (0 == pUnknown->Release()) 
        pUnknown = NULL;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The code in the question and in this response is incorrect. IUnknown::Release() returns a ULONG, not an HRESULT. The ULONG is usually the refcount of the object. It is not an indicator of whether the Release() succeeded or failed.

See IUnknown::Release() documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682317(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @ants: I was just going along with the comments in WinError.h:
`// The return value of COM functions and methods is an HRESULT.`
guess then thats fixed up then as well, thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 4):

The commonly taken route for dealing with COM resources is to employ RAII and let helper classes like ATLs [`CComPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98%28VS.80%29.aspx) or [`CComQIPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc177dxw%28VS.80%29.aspx) handle reference counting for you as far as possible.

```
void f() {
    CComPtr<IDirect3DDevice> sp3dDev;
    getDevice(&sp3dDev);
    // ... do stuff
} // smart pointer gets destroyed, calls Release() if valid
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could do what you originally wrote, then you would violate type safety:

```
IDirect3DDevice *blah;
IUnknown *bar;
IUnknown *&unknown= blah;
unknown= bar;
```

Clearly, assigning `bar` to `unknown` would mean that `blah` points to an `IUnknown`, which would violate type safety.

[nobugz's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350531/problem-with-d3d-com/2350562#2350562) is probably what you want to do, although I would argue that setting those pointers to NULL doesn't increase the quality of your code. If you need to ensure that other code won't `Release` multiple times, you probably should go fix that code rather than making buggy code not fail.

Comment: I see where it would cause a problem, but I was getting problems even up casting a IDirect3DDevice* to an IUnknown*, which should work

Comment: You were casting to IUnknown *&, which is a reference to a pointer of IUnknown. Look at the signature of SafeRelease.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with DirectX in a while but I remember it has a `SAFE_RELEASE` macro somewhere in it's headers. Google code search shows it's in `dxutil.h`.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using macros for a few reasons, one being that I can't check is the release succeeds, though when I googled "SafeRelease D3D COM" I got nothing of use